# How to import token of a discord bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, discord.py

I'm trying to put my Discord bot online with Heroku, but I can't figure out how I can import the token to the code.
I already created the var with the righ token at Heroku. The token was in my code, but, of course, I can't let it there.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
from random import randint
import os

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=';')

# Bot token for Heroku
Client.run(str(os.environ.get('BOT_TOKEN')))
```

What I need to do now?

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to keep the token inside of the code?

What exactly is the error? Does the app on heroku crash?

Comment: It looks like you set a config var using the commandline interface: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: @Rickyy Cause with the token, anyone can modify the bot.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh It's already done.

Comment: @Rickyy on heroku the bot simply don't starts cause the lack of the token.

Comment: @KlebersonGomes But if you put the token in the code or in a environment variable shouldn't make a difference, does it?

Comment: Have you tried to print the bot token? Is the environment variable set?

Comment: @Rickyy How do I set the environment variable? And where? I searched on google, but couldn't find anything.
And I don know if it will make difference. The token just can't stay public.

Comment: You can use the site posted by @PatrickHaugh - Either via command line or via webinterface. Both should work fine.

Comment: @Rickyy Oh, config vars is the same as enviroment variables? So it's already done correctly!

Comment: Then try to just print the variable and check if it **really** is setup correctly. If os.environ.get returns None, then the variable does not seem to be setup correctly